# Вывести QString на консоль при помощи QDebug

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring

Всем привет, не могу разобраться с таким вопросом:
У меня есть строка QString с кириллицей. Мне необходимо вывести это строку на консоль, но из за неправильной кодировки получается набор непонятных символов.

```
QString text = "Русский текст";
qDebug() << text; //результат "??????? ?????"
```

Я пытался преобразовать строку в UTF - 16, Таким вод кодом:

```
QString new_text = QString::fromUtf16(text);  //в этой строке выдает ошибку
qDebug() << new_text;
```

Подскажите. как можно преобразовать строку с кириллицей, чтобы она корректно выводилась в qDebug.

Важное замечание, строки программа получает извне, поэтому в коде их задать нельзя, нужно преобразовать именно переменную типа QString.

*QT 6.1.3, VS 2019*

**UPD**
Попробовал преобразовать не в UTF - 16, а в UTF - 8, но также выдает ошибку

```
    QString text = "Русский текст";
    QString new_text = QString::toUtf8(text);  //тут выдает ошибку
    qDebug() << new_text;
```

***UPD На данный момент для меня вопрос не актуален, но учитывая что он собрал более 1К просмотров, думаю другим пользователям он может быть интересен. Поэтому если кто то предложит универсальное решение, я с радостью приму ответ.***

Comment: `fromUtf16` значит **из** UTF16. А первое, что вам необходимо сделать - узнать кодировку входной строки и требуемую кодировку при выводе.

Comment: @user7860670, я так понимаю на выходе все таки не UTF - 16, а UTF - 8 нужна, входная строка ASCII

Comment: @user7860670 я попробовал "QString new_text = QString::toUtf8(text);"
но тоже ошибка

Comment: Входная строка не может быть ASCII, так как в ней русские буквы. А если бы она была ASCII, то не отличалась бы от UTF-8.

Comment: @user7860670, Значит видимо я неправильно написал, и исходный текст как раз в UTF-16, а мне надо преобразовать его в формат читаемый консолью

Comment: Потому что там `CP866`

Comment: `Qt6` перешёл с `UTF-16` на `UTF-8`

Comment: `QString text = u8"Русский текст";`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте правильно установить локаль:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug()<<"тест1"; // <- выводится ерунда
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    qDebug()<<"тест2"; // <- а теперь корректный вывод

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант про локаль не подумал, и с локалью действительно работает.
Однако по мне не самый оптимальный способ, так как при добавлении еще нескольких языков, придется добавлять еще локали. Хотелось бы найти более универсальный способ.

Comment: Способ универсальный. Вы что пытаетесь сделать? Перевод сообщений на разные языки? Тогда Вам нужно использовать QTranslator (tr("")) и соответственно все сообщения переводить на разные языки, которые будут подключаться правильно в зависимости от языка локали

Comment: Пишу техническую программу, текст может содержать не только символы русского языка, но и различные спецсимволы, и символы других языков. Да и основная цель вопроса, именно разобраться как работает перевод кодировок в с++.

Comment: @AndreyM Тогда Вам нужно правильно сформулировать задачу и вопрос. Под Ваш вопрос мой ответ правильный. Именно так и нужно делать в реальности. QDebuq вообще не правильно использовать для вывода пользовательской информации. Для этого можно генерировать отчет о работе программы в файл, в виде рисунка, да вообще в tex, pdf и т.д. В случае корректного пользовательского интерфейса также вы выводите сообщения через tr("") и в зависимости от локали используйте заранее подготовленный словарь. Если же Вам надо выводить разные символы используйте UTF-16 и конкретный индекс символа.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло это

```
system("chcp 65001");
```

Comment: Но это же не универсальное решение, к тому же оно зависит от типа операционной системы

Comment: Согласен, но судя по описанию, перед автором не стоит задача написания кроссплатформенного кода.

Comment: В том то и дело, что автор ищет универсального ответа, посмотрите на комментарии к моему ответу.